# How to update an image in sql using php

Tags: php, mysql, image, session, sql-update

I want to update or set a photo on specific user, when I tried to upload an image, the image is not uploaded on my folder "upload"  and the name of the photo (which is a number but 0 e.g: 1.jpg) is inserted in database and the file extension is missing inside the database can someone help me with this

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../db_connection.php");

$seller_id = $_SESSION['seller_id'];
$trade_name = $_POST ['trade_name'];
$s_address = $_POST ['s_address'];
$opening_time = $_POST ['opening_time'];
$opening_days = $_POST ['opening_days'];
$order_cutoff = $_POST ['order_cutoff'];
$seller_delivery_time = $_POST ['seller_delivery_time'];
$area_covered_delivery = $_POST ['area_covered_delivery'];
$delivery_fee = $_POST ['delivery_fee'];

 $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['s_image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$sql = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE selling_details
                   SET
                   opening_time = '$opening_time',
                   opening_days = '$opening_days',
                   order_cutoff = '$order_cutoff',
                   seller_delivery_time = '$seller_delivery_time',
                   area_covered_delivery = '$area_covered_delivery',
                   delivery_fee = '$delivery_fee'
                   WHERE seller_id= '" . $_SESSION['seller_id'] . "' ");
            if ($sql)
    {
        $id = mysqli_insert_id($db);
        $filename = $id.'.'.$extension;

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['s_image']['tmp_name'], 'upload/'.$filename))
        {
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error occured : " . mysqli_error($db);
    }

$sql2 = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE seller
                   SET
                   trade_name = '$trade_name',
                   s_address = '$s_address',
                   s_image = '$filename' 
                   WHERE seller_id= '" . $_SESSION['seller_id'] . "' ");
            if ($sql2)
    {

        header('location: seller_menu.php');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error occured : " . mysqli_error($db);
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['s_image']['tmp_name'], 'upload/'.$filename)) be carefull with paths

Comment: .. And we don't have to tell you that your database is vulnerable to SQL injections and that you are planning to use prepared statements to prevent that :)

Comment: can you please explain what you want... your image is not uploading in the folder or not saved in the database ?

Comment: Sir it's not uploading in the folder but can be saved in database but when it saves in database the value is always "0."  @Nawin

Comment: before submitting to database.can you please echo the query and just tell me the results.echo $sql

Comment: what is the type of `s_image` field?

Comment: it's varchar sir @Nawin

Answer (score 0):

Try like this... If your field is `varchar` means it will work. and you need to declare the variable using `.`[concodinate] operator. Not tested check and let me know.

```
$sql2 = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE seller
               SET
               trade_name = '".$trade_name."',
               s_address = '".$s_address."',
               s_image = '".$filename."' 
               WHERE seller_id= '" . $_SESSION['seller_id'] . "' ");
```

**Edited:**

Try to change like this because if your file upload complete then save into your DB is correct way...In your code is run the second `sql2` query if not file upload into the folder.

```
if ($sql) {
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($db);
    $filename = $id.'.'.$extension;

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['s_image']['tmp_name'], 'upload/'.$filename)) {
        $sql2 = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE seller
               SET
               trade_name = '".$trade_name."',
               s_address = '".$s_address."',
               s_image = '".$filename."' 
               WHERE seller_id= '" . $_SESSION['seller_id'] . "' ");
        if ($sql2) {

            header('location: seller_menu.php');
        }else{
            echo "error occured : " . mysqli_error($db);
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "error occured : " . mysqli_error($db);
}
```

Comment: Sir the value is still the same "0."

Comment: Sir it says: Undefined index: s_image

Comment: In my actual code it's Line 15 and 31 both are undefined index: s_image

Comment: print your `$_FILES`. and check post name is `s_image` is correct.

Comment: Sir I've already fixed, the photo is now uploading, but the filename is not changing it is always 0.png

Answer (score 0):

$upload_dir = "upload";                 // The directory for the images to be saved in
    $upload_path = $upload_dir."/";

```
$userfile_tmp = $_FILES['s_image'.$i]['tmp_name'];
$filename  = basename($_FILES['s_image'.$i]['name']);
$file_Size = $_FILES['s_image']['size'];    

$extension = strtolower(substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1));
if (empty($extension)) {$error='No extension exist!';}

if(isset($_FILES['s_image']['name']) && $_FILES['s_image']['name']==true && $file_Size >0 && $error=='')
{
        $filename = $id.'.'.$extension;
        $new_image_location=$upload_path.$filename;
        //chmod($new_image_location, 0777);

        if(move_uploaded_file($userfile_tmp, $new_image_location))
        {
            $sql2 = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE seller
                   SET
                   trade_name = '$trade_name',
                   s_address = '$s_address',
                   s_image = '$filename' 
                   WHERE seller_id= '" . $_SESSION['seller_id'] . "' ");
        }else{
            echo 'upload folder permission required!!';
            //chmod($new_image_location, 0777);             
        }       
}
```

Comment: Sir I have two queries as you can see above, I can't follow your suggested answer, I don't know where to insert those codes

Comment: -- Update query $id = mysqli_insert_id($db);

$id should be 0 because there is no insert query yet to execute. So u should use other identity or $_SESSION['seller_id'];

$id =$_SESSION['seller_id'];